# How do I make the top of an image blend with a background color CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following in my html file:

```css
.sectionone{
width: 100%;
background-color: blue;
background-image: image.png;
background-size: contain;
background-position: bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="sectionone">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

But when the screen is smaller and I get to see the background color I can see a very thin white line between the top of the image and the bottom of the background color. Is there any way to either blend or fix this?
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a full example of the problem you are having?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Hello, I just added more. I hope that helps explain the issue. If there is anything else I can add please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Please put up a proper working snippet. This needs to include the image in a way that we can see it, ie the full url(https://….). At the moment you have background-image: image.png; which does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used contain instead of cover to keep the image at the bottom of the div regardless of the height I gave it. Cover does get rid of the line but also cuts off the edges of the background image at certain heights.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple dear! I have 2 solutions for this problem. 
**First:** If you have not reset the whole CSS then do it. May be it will solve the problem. For resetting the CSS write this code at the top of your CSS file.

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
```

**Second** Give top negative margin to your image. like this

```
img{margin-top: -5px}
```

I hope one of them will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, I do have that at the very top of my CSS and in my case the image is not defined in the html only as the background-image in the css file. In that case, how can I write this: ```img{margin-top: -5px}```. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Oh, Yes I caught your problem. I tried your code on pc then I understand what is the problem. You are using the `background-size: contain;` property therefore it is behaving like this. Try to add this `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Yes, I was using cover before. The only issue is that I want the whole image to be visible. So I changed it to contain and added a background color that matches the top of the image so that when the image is smaller it will appear as if the top just extends.

Comment: Dear! `cover `also shows the whole image. It will not cut your image. Try using it

Comment: I ended up going to contain because it allows me to resize that div while keeping the background image at the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try using a negative value of margin-top for the next div after `img` for a quick fix.

You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Hi, all the content for that section is within the div I placed in the code above. I tried doing a -1px for the margin-top of that div and the line still shows up. I will also add a screenshot if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your code ,you could use the background-blend-mode attribute in css file for blending your image with the background color.
Blend Mode helps to blend your image thicker or lighten with the background.

```
.sectionone {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
        background-image: image.png;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: bottom;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        min-height: 500px;
        background-blend-mode: thicker; //changes in your code
        }
```

Hope, you could get a solution.

Comment: Hello, I tried that and thick but the line still shows up. Thanks for the reply!